# Is there another way than passing by reference to do what I want

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following data structure:

A `Contract` has an array `projects`, which can have X number of projects. Each `Project` has an array, `subProjects`, which contain the same `Project` type, so theoretically you could have an infinite tree of Project-SubProjects-Project...

Anyway, each project has a unique ID, and I need to search for a given project AND make a modification to that project, starting at the top level, and then store the changed contract back to my session. Currently, I'm doing it via a recursive function that returns a reference to the project it finds, but the more I'm searching, the more it seems people don't like PHP references. I'm not sure why, could someone explain the problems? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Some code:

```
// Get the associative array version of the contract (it's stored as JSON)
$contract = json_decode($contract, true);

if(array_key_exists('projects', $contract))
{
    $resultProject = &$this->findProject($contract['projects'], $projectId);

    if($resultProject)
    {
        $resultProject[$inputData['propertyName']] = $inputData['value'];

         \Session::put('workingContract', json_encode($contract));

        // return 200
    }
}

// Return 404

/**
 * Performs a depth-first search to find a project.
 *
 * @param array $projects
 * @param $projectId
 * @return null
 */
private function &findProject(array &$projects, $projectId)
{
    foreach($projects as &$project)
    {
        if($project['_id']['$id'] == $projectId)
        {
            return $project;
        }

        if(array_key_exists('subProjects', $project))
        {
            $result = &$this->findProject($project['subProjects'], $projectId);
            return $result;
        }
    }

    $null = null; // TODO: shitty hack for inability to return null when function returns a reference. Need to rethink use of references in general. Is there another way???
    return $null;
}
```

Comment: I've upvoted just to know why people are do not like references. Because PHP is not C++, where pointers are just about everywhere? Well, I don't.

Comment: 1 suggestion is that you can use an object, instead of passing arrays by reference.

Comment: @om_deshpande do you seem something wrong with the way I'm doing it currently, or are you just offering another way of doing it because that's what I asked about? I'm concerned with why others feel references are "messy" or that they add "code smell". I feel that they're in PHP for a reason and if it seems to me that this is an appropriate use case.

Comment: Ryan, people usually say whatever they feel like and it's not difficult to invent a scenario that proves their case right. Yes, they exist for a reason and are widely used. Like everything, in hands of a bad programmer they can be a powerful gunshot to the foot. You have a use scenario for them, so just use them. If they had no purpose, they'd never be there to begin with. And don't trust whatever people write on internet, bear in mind  that 99% of that is pure bullshit.

Comment: @N.B. OK sounds good...I was more curious if my use case was valid. I mean, it works...it gets the job done, but I'm always open to cleaner, more elegant solutions. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I agree with @N.B. There's nothing inherently wrong with your approach. It's just a matter of preference and what a developer is used to. Newer programmers will find working with objects easier and if asked to work with references they'll struggle with the gotcha's. But, for someone who understands references well, there's nothing wrong with that approach. I made that suggestion on the basis on code maintainability.

Comment: It's easier for most devs to read, understand and track objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create an array with all your projects (a flat array), indexed by `ID`. Let each `Project` object have an `->id` property that you can refer to. Problem solved?

Also, if the `Project` doesn't exist in the flat array, I see absolutely no problem in returning `null`.

```
class Contract {
   private $projects_flat = array();

   ....

   private function get_project($id) {
      return (isset($this->projects_flat[$id]) ? $this->projects_flat[$id] : null)
   }
}
```